# NSDate comparision in xcode4.5

Tags: ios6, xcode4.5

I have the following code

```
NSDate * selectedDate = self.datePicker.date;

NSLog(@"The date selected is %@ and initialdate is %@", selectedDate, initialDate);

NSLog(@"the expression value is %i", [self.initialDate isEqualToDate:selectedDate]);
```

Which prints the following

```
The date selected is 2012-09-24 18:49:04 +0000 and initialdate is 2012-09-24 18:49:04 +0000

the expression value is 0
```

I am using xcode4.5 and targetted to ios6. The same code in xcode4.4 prints `1`(They are equal)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it.

when I added the following line

```
NSLog(@"Initaldate with time intervel since 1970 %f  and selecteddate %f", [initialDate timeIntervalSince1970], [selectedDate timeIntervalSince1970]);
```

It prints same value in iOS 5 but different value in iOS6.